# How can I prepopulate the 'Add Contact' activity with a last name field in Android 2.1?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-activity

I would like to show the 'Add contact' activity prepopulated with a last name (also known as "family name" and "surname"). Currently I can only get it to populate the first name. Here's my code:

```
Intent intentAddContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

intentAddContact.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Mickey Mouse");
intentAddContact.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,"01234567891");
intentAddContact.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "mickey@disney.com");

startActivityForResult(intentAddContact, ADD_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

This puts "Mickey Mouse" in the first name field. I need "Mickey" to go in the first name and "Mouse" to go in the last name. My app needs to run on Android 2.1 (API level 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the stock "Add Contact" activity in AOSP only support the full name to be supplied (see source code for [`EditContactActivity.createContact()`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/ui/EditContactActivity.java) and [`EntityModifier.parseExtras()`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/model/EntityModifier.java)).

One way to approximate what you want is to insert the contact information into the provider directly and then launch the "Edit Contact" activity as follow:

```
private void enlistMickey() throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {
    final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder;

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
    ops.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Mickey");
    builder.withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Mouse");
    ops.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "01234567891");
    ops.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(Email.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(Email.DATA, "mickey@disney.com");
    ops.add(builder.build());

    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    final ContentProviderResult[] res = cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    final Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.getContactLookupUri(cr, res[0].uri);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

One notable difference using this "insert and edit" mechanism compared to the "add" method is that the aggregation process in the provider will be more likely to prevent us from creating a new contact if an existing one with matching data already existed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this insert a contact into the user's addressbook regardless of what they do on the edit activity? If so, this is not a viable solution because I need the user to review the information for the new contact, then decide whether they want to add them.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, this is an approximation, not an exact replacement :) You should be able to check the result code in the onActivityResult() to delete the contact if the user clicked on the "Revert" button though.

Comment: The problem is relying on the user to revert the change. What if they decide to do something else or their phone runs out of battery? By default the contact is inserted without the user's permission.

Comment: Good point on the permission issue (I think there are ways to mark the pre-inserted contact so we can clean it up later, but that beside the point). It seems likely to me now that it would probably be best if you wrote your own "Add Contact" activity instead of using the one from the system to avoid more issues (For example, it will save the contact if the user hit the back key, which might not always be their intention).

Comment: Yep, good comment, think that's what I'm going to have to do if there's no other way. Seems a shame though that this seemingly basic functionality is missing - what's the point of an 'Add Contact' activity if you can't add the person's surname?

Comment: Thanks for your help, answer accepted because what I'm asking for is not possible